# Python display custom error message / traceback on every exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, python-decorators, traceback

Does Python support a way to display the same custom error message for every exception / raise / assert (no matter where the code broke)?

My current crack at it uses a decorator. I have a function `main` and it displays the traceback fine, but I want it to also print `my_var` (which is INSIDE the function scope) every time ANY error is thrown. So obviously there is a scope problem with this - it's just to illustrate what I want to do. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
import traceback

def exit_with_traceback(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            # how do I get this to print my_var AND the traceback?
            print(traceback.format_exc())
    return wrap
        
@exit_with_traceback
def main(bar=1):
    my_var = 'hello world'  # variable specific to main()
    return bar + 1

main(bar=None)  # run main() to throw the exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to override the [excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) function in `sys` module. From its documentation:

> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls
> sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception
> instance, and a traceback object.

So the code may look something like this (I've used your example):

```
import sys


# define custom exception hook
def custom_exception_hook(exc_type, value, traceback):
    print('Custom exception hook')
    print('Type:', exc_type)
    print('Value:', value)
    print('Traceback:', traceback)
    lc = traceback.tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals
    print(lc.get('my_var'))  # this prints "hello world"


# override the default exception hook
sys.excepthook = custom_exception_hook


def main(bar=1):
    my_var = 'hello world'  # variable specific to main()
    return bar + 1


main(bar=None)  # run main() to throw the exception
```

The overriding of `sys.excepthook` won't work from IDLE, but it works just fine from command line. Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This is close to what I had in mind, but doesn't print out the value of `my_var` which I want in the exception.

Comment: What about looking up local variables in the traceback? For example something like this (I tried specific for the example code): "traceback.tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals"

Comment: This is a workable approach. I've edited your solution and accepted.